# Moving Background on Mouse - Preventing Image from Snapping to New Location on First Interaction?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a background that moves with your mouse, but when the user first moves their mouse into frame, the image snaps to a position and it's really jarring. I cannot figure out how to make this go away and make the experience smoother. Any ideas?

https://codepen.io/robertsaget/pen/NWoLMpx

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    var x = -(e.pageX + this.offsetLeft) / 20;
    var y = -(e.pageY + this.offsetTop) / 20;
    document.querySelector('.landing-content').style.backgroundPosition = x + 'px ' + y + 'px';
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.landing-content {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/kO2eQtC.jpg);
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="landing-content">
    <section class="slider"></section>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```